# Is there a way to make `cargo check` always show warnings, not just on the first attempt?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Here's my first invocation of `cargo check`:

```
$ cargo check
    Updating crates.io index
   Compiling num-traits v0.2.6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
   Compiling num-integer v0.1.39                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
   Compiling num-iter v0.1.37                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    Checking byteorder v1.2.6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    Checking adler32 v1.0.3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    Checking bitflags v1.0.4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    Checking bit-vec v0.5.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    Checking libc v0.2.43                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    Checking inflate v0.4.3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    Checking deflate v0.7.19                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    Checking png v0.12.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    Checking cargo_check_test v0.1.0 (/tmp/cargo_check_test)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
warning: unused import: `std::path::Path`                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  --> src/main.rs:11:5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
11 | use std::path::Path;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
   |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   = note: #[warn(unused_imports)] on by default

    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 11.30s
```

And here's the second:

```
$ cargo check
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.02s
```

Is there a way to make `cargo check` always show me all warnings, not just at the first attempt?

Comment: cargo clean + cargo build ?

Comment: @Stargateur is that the only / main solution?

Comment: Basically, even if cargo have an option for that you ask for something that need to compile again all your project, so... yes.